# Adding/Subtracting big number to and from a character

Tags: java

For case #1, adding 2 to 'a' gives us 'c'.

How can I write a program so that adding 2 to 'z' gives 'b' as an output and subtracting 3 from 'a' gives 'x' as an output?

In other words, I want only alphabet character as an output. No matter how big number you are adding or subtracting to and from the character, I always expect the output between a and z inclusive.

```
case #1
public void addNumberToCharacter{
    char character = 'a' + 2;
    System.out.println(character); // 'c'
}

case #2
public void addNumberToCharacter{
    char character = 'z' + 2;
    System.out.println(character); // 'b'
}

case #3
public void addNumberToCharacter{
    char character = 'a' - 3;
    System.out.println(character); // 'x'
}
```

Comment: just mod your adding number by 26

Comment: The modulus operator `%` is your friend.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet for case #3?

Comment: @Kayaman Upvoted, but % is really a remainder operator.  -3 and +2 are congruent, modulo 5, but -3%5 is not equal to 2%5.

Comment: @MikeHousky indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle two cases you might also require:

1. uppercase and lowercase;
2. adding/subtracting number whose absolute value is bigger than **26**;

And here is the method you can refer to:

```
private static void addNumToChar(int a, char c0) {
    char c = 'a';
    if(Character.isUpperCase(c0)) {
        c = 'A';
    }
    while (a < 0) a += 26;
    char c1 = (char) (c + (c0 - c + a) % 26);
    System.out.println(c1);
}
```

Run the test as follows:

```
    addNumToChar(2, 'B'); // D
    addNumToChar(2, 'b'); // d
    addNumToChar(261, 'B'); // C
    addNumToChar(261, 'b'); // c

    addNumToChar(-2, 'B'); // Z
    addNumToChar(-2, 'b'); // z

    addNumToChar(-261, 'B'); // A
    addNumToChar(-261, 'b'); // a
```

Comment: What about addNumToChar(3, 'c')? This function doesn't give 'f'

Comment: Sorry for not testing more cases, I just updated the solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the **issues** I made, man ~~ my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

After you add or subtract, correct with:

```
character = (character + 26 - 'a')%26 + 'a';
```

Java's x%y operator gives the remainder from integer division of x by y.  Subtracting 'a' gives the offset from the start of the lowercase alphabet, and then adding 26 guarantees a positive sum, provided you didn't add an offset less than -26 or subtract more than +26.

Comment: What if I want to add an offset less than -26 or subtract more than +26?

Comment: @user7755336 Then add a larger multiple of 26 in the above correction, or add/subtract `offset%26`, reducing the range of the offset to -25..+25, but still correct (modulo 26).  Or you can use `((ch - 'a')%26 + 26)%26`.  If this is a rotation cipher, though, you should probably limit the shift to 1..25 in the forward direction and report an input error if outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

```
public char number(int num, char c){ // -- num =29, char= 'd'
    int n = c - 96 ; // n = 4
    n = n+(num%26); // n = 4 + 3 = 7
    if(n > 26){ return (char)(n-26); } // doesnot follow
    else if(n < 0){ return (char)(n+26); } // doesnot follow
    else { return (char)(n); } // return g

}
```

You can try this method. It can handle positive as well as negative number.

Answer (score 0):

use that one :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c= 'a' - 1;
    if(!(c>=97 && c<=122)) {
        if(c>=123)
            c= (char) (c-26);
        else
            c= (char) (c+26);
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```